# Python partitioning string list by using for loop conditional statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to remove all letters after a certain string, for example, removing words after `Hello` and `Hi` inside `my_list` (just like my code below), and return a new cleaned list.

I tried to use partition inside for loop conditional statement but it just returned the original list. Is there any way to modify `my_list` by using partition or other methods? Here is what my current code is:

```
my_list = ['Say Hello to Python', 'Say Hi to HiPython', 'Goodbye Python']
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if 'Hello' in my_list[i] == True:
        my_list[i] = my_list[i].partition('Hello')[0]
    if 'Hi' in my_list[i] == True:
        my_list[i] = my_list[i].partition('Hi')[0]
```

Expected:
`['Say ', 'Say ', 'Goodbye Python']`

Actual Output:
`['Hello Python', 'HiPython', 'Goodbye Python']`

Comment: Remove the `== True` from your if statements. Usually they're just not necessary, but in this case they're changing the meaning of your code from what you intend. It's evaluated as `if 'Hello' in (my_list[i] == True):`, which will always be `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split()` method . I updated all you can try and check it now.

```
my_list = ['Say Hello to Python', 'Say Hi to HiPython', 'Goodbye Python']
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if 'Hello' in my_list[i]:
        delete = 'Hello'
        get = my_list[i].split(delete, 1)[0]
        my_list[i] = get
    if 'Hi' in my_list[i]:
        delete = 'Hi'
        get = my_list[i].split(delete, 1)[0]
        my_list[i] = get


print(my_list)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
['Say ', 'Say ', 'Goodbye Python']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if 'Hello' in my_list[i] == True:
```

is a check for if the word `Hello` is in the boolean value `my_list[i] == True` - which is obviously never the case.
Try

```
if 'Hello' in my_list[i]:
```

and accordingly with `'Hi'`.

Answer (score 0):

1.Your conditionals are incorrect
2.Use proper if/else statements

```
my_list = ['Say Hello to Python', 'Say Hi to HiPython', 'Goodbye Python']
new_list=[]
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if 'Hello' in my_list[i]:
        print(my_list[i].partition('Hello'))
        new_list.append(my_list[i].partition('Hello')[0])
    elif 'Hi' in my_list[i]:
        print(my_list[i].partition('Hi'))
        new_list.append(my_list[i].partition('Hi')[0])
    else:
        new_list.append(my_list[i])
```

new_list

```
['Say ', 'Say ', 'Goodbye Python']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a clean and fairly pythonic method. Easy to add any other strings you want to remove.

```
def fix_list(list_of_strings):

    for item in list_of_strings:
        if 'Hello' in item:
            yield item.replace('Hello', '')
        elif 'Hi' in item:
            yield item.replace('Hi', '')
        else:
            yield item


def main():

    my_list = ['Say Hello to Python', 'Say Hi to HiPython', 'Goodbye Python']

    return list(fix_list(my_list))
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work, as it only removes the searched for word, rather than everything after the searched for word.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this in slightly more Pythonic code, where we iterate over items in your list directly, rather than over a range of the list. Instead of editing the list in place we create a new list. I prefer this method as it leads to less confusing results in my experience. 
One other point: be careful as to what you want to happen in the case that both 'Hello' and 'Hi' are in your sentence. You haven't specified what should happen in this case.

```py
my_list = ['Say Hello to Python', 'Say Hi to Python', 'Goodbye Python']
output_list = []
for sentence in my_list:
    search_word = ''
    if 'Hello' in sentence:
        search_word = 'Hello'
    if 'Hi' in sentence:
        search_word = 'Hi'
    if not search_word:
        output_list.append(sentence)
        continue

    # get the index of the last bit of the string
    # you will keep and split on that
    index = sentence.find(sentence.partition(search_word)[1])
    output_list.append(sentence[:index])
print(output_list)
>>> ['Say ', 'Say ', 'Goodbye Python']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use positional indexing to achieve this as well. But first you need to find the position of the word you are searching for on the given string. You can do that with the [find](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method. Then you can retrieve the string from the beginning to the final position given by the start of the word you are searching for. I chose to store the values in a new list.

```
my_list = ['Say Hello to Python', 'Say Hi to HiPython', 'Goodbye Python']
result = []
a, b = ("Hello", "Hi")
for x in my_list:
    if a in x:
        result.append(x[0:x.find(a)])
    elif b in x:
        result.append(x[0:x.find(b)])
    else:
        result.append(x)
print(result)
```